# How to upload a file to Amazon S3 with the kms role?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I want to upload a file to Amazon S3 from an environment which gives me IAM credentials. However I am getting this error :

`Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: EF93490A8356F585)`

The IAM roles are as follows :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sam-94a493b-dev"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sam-bbcb194a493b-dev/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:000351272236:key/9b7a989c-ee8e-4c83-b765-6debe0f94eaa"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I use default client to access Amazon S3 client and `putObject` method to put an object to a the bucket with `fileNameWithPath` (path/in/s3/filename.ext)
The code to access s3 is as follows :

```
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
s3client.putObject(bucketName, fileNameWithPath, file)
```

And the error I get is :

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: EF93490A8356F585)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1587) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.163.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1257) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.163.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1029) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.163.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:741) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.163.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:715) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.163.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.163.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:665) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.163.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:647) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.163.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:511) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.163.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4227) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.163.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4174) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.163.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1722) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.163.jar!/:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1577) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.163.jar!/:?]
    at com.example.services.S3Service.uploadFile(S3Service.java:63) ~[classes!/:?]
```

My aws sdk version is - `1.11.163` which should have have signature version 4 by default. I am not sure where the problem lies

I have already tried setting various SSEAlgorithm in `putObject` like **'AES256'** and **'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'** but those didn't help.

Any leads would be appriciated.

Comment: Try to specify  the `region` param as well. Some regions requires that to use the correct signature version

Comment: This didn't help :(

Comment: What is the rest of your code? What is `file`?

Comment: I think you have to specify the KMS key ID in the request https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-the-rest-api-to-encrypt-s3-objects-by-using-aws-kms/

Comment: `file` is the file I am trying to upload

Comment: Thanks @BretC for the link. It was very useful. I solved this issue by specifying the x-amz-server-side-encryption : 'aws:kms' in the object metadata of the request. Thanks a lot again :)

Comment: I'll post the solution below. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by following the following steps -

1. Explicitly specifying the `request` via `PutObjectRequest`
2. Creating a `new ObjectMetadata` and setting the `SSEAlgorithm` to it - "aws:kms".
3. Attach the `objectMetadata` to the `request`.
4. Send the `request` via `putObject` method.

Here is code -

```
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, ruleFilePath, file);
    ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    objectMetadata.setSSEAlgorithm("aws:kms");
    request.setMetadata(objectMetadata);
    this.s3client.putObject(request);
```